# Perl regex: How to find in a file a word typed by a user

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I am writing a script to read a LOG file. I want the user to type a word and then look it up and print the line (from a string) matching the word.

I'm just learning Perl so please be very specific and simple so that I can understand it.

```
 print "Please Enter the word to find: ";
 chomp ($userInput = <STDIN>);

 while ($line = <INPUT>)
 if ($line =~ /userInput/)
 print $line;
```

I know that this is not perfect but I'm just learning.

Comment: If a user inputs `dog`, do you want to match `dogs` and `odograph` and the like?

Comment: Nop I want to match the word the are looking in the file log. if they type IP I want to find the line that has the IP word and print to the screen the line.

Comment: You know, you could always just do `grep word file`. If you read `man grep` you will see there's a lot of functionality you can use.

Comment: In Perl, couldn't there be a problem with code execution when user input is run as a regex (ala `(?{delete file system})`) ?

Answer (score 2):

You were close. You need to expand the variable in the pattern match.

```
print "Please Enter the word to find: ";
chomp ($userInput = <STDIN>);

while ($line = <INPUT>) {
    if ($line =~ /$userInput/) {  # note extra dollar sign
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Be aware that that is a pattern match, so you are searching with a string that potentially contains wildcards in it.  If you want a literal string, put a `\Q` in front of the variable as you interpolate it:   `/\Q$userInput/`.

Comment: @NewLearner What error? I presume there is more to your program, since you are assuming that INPUT is an open filehandle.

Comment: You'll need some word boundary logic to meet the OP's newly clarified requirements, I think.

Comment: @pilcrow Without being given sample input lines and sample query words, showing which should match and which should fail to match, it is impossible to do. The way boundaries work is too tricky to just guess.  Wrapping `\b` around it is not going to work right in many cases.

Comment: @tchrist, point taken.  However, we know that @NewLearner doesn't want an input of `dog` to match `pseudograph`.

Comment: @pilcrow And what should `dog.` match? Put a pair of `\b` around that and it will fail to match the last word in a sentance. Anyway, I don’t get that from what they wrote. There simply isn’t enough info for us to know what is correct here.

Comment: when i use this it doesn't print anything to the screen.

Comment: @NewLearner It’s not a complete program. If you run that **and that alone**, you will have failed to open any input file. It assumes you have correctly opened the right input file into the handle `INPUT`. Your original snippet was incomplete. I figured you knew what else you were missing. I have no idea where you want to get your input file from; there’s no way I could know that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like **.*\bWORD\b.*** might work (thou it is not tested)

```
print $line if ($line =~ /.*\bWORD\b/)
```

@NewLearner

\b is for word boundaries

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: thank for the answer. what does the b do in that piece of code.

Comment: You can’t use `\b` if you don’t know whether they entered an alphanumeric string or not.  Imagine what happens if they enter `%` for their string:  you now force there to be alphanumerics next to the percent sign! Remember that `\b` is only going to do what you expect when it is touching alphanumerics, and perhaps not even then.

Comment: The `/.*/` in this code is useless because it doesn't change the results, and wasteful because it forces Perl to search *backwards* from the end of the line to find the *last* occurrence of `WORD`. `/\bWORD\b/` is far better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing just one loopup, using a while loop is fine. Though of course you'll need to fix your syntax.

You could also use `grep`:

```
print grep /$userInput/, <INPUT>;
```

If you want to do multiple lookups, you can either reopen the file handle (if the file is large), or store it in an array:

```
print grep /$userInput/, @array;
```

You'll have meta characters in your input, of course. This can be a good thing, or bad, depending on your users. For example, an experienced user would recognize the option to refine his search by entering a search term such as `^foo(?=bar)`, whereas other people may get very confused when they can't find the string `foo+bar`.

A way to escape meta characters is by using `quotemeta` on your input. Another is to use `\Q ... \E` inside your regex.

```
$userInput = quotemeta($userInput);
# or
print grep /\Q$userInput\E/, <INPUT>;
```

I believe if I were you, I would use a subroutine for the lookup. That way you can perform as many lookups as you like rather handily.

```
use strict;
use warnings; # ALWAYS use these

print "Please Enter the word to find: ";
chomp (my $userInput = <>);  # <> is a more flexible handle
print lookup($userInput);

sub lookup {
    my $word = shift;
    open my $fh, "<", $inputfile or die $!;
    my @hits;
    while (<$fh>) {
        push @hits, $_ if /\Q$word\E/;
    }
    return @hits;
}
```